# How to get output from a loop which is inside a function in php?

Tags: php, function

I've been scraching my head for hours over this problem. I'm basically trying to fetch values from a loop inside a function to pass it to another foreach loop to get the desired results. And it is not working as I intend to. please, point me in the right direction.
Here is the code:

```
function ff($s) {

    $project="";
    foreach ($s as $i => $r) {

        $r["friend_one"] == $_SESSION['uname'] ? $friends[] = $r["friend_two"] : $friends[] = $r["friend_one"]; 

        $friend = $friends[$i];
        $totalids=$project->totalids($_SESSION['uname'],$friend);
    }
    return $totalids;
}

$totalid = ff($f);
print_r($totalid);

foreach ($totalid as $v) {

    $id=$v['user_id'];
    //other logic to get desired result      
}
```

Comment: Where is `$project->totalids()` defined?  From what I can see, `$projects` is a blank string.  Your question is also hard to understand.

Comment: That is actually a method from class pulled through dbconfig.php file @JuliePelletier

Answer (score 0):

Like most languages, the PHP `return` statement breaks the function, so your function will only get through one run of the `foreach` block before resuming the rest of the code. To get around this, you can dump the outputs into a variable, and then return that variable after the `foreach` block, so instead of this:

```
    return $totalids;
}
```

Use this:

```
    array_push($output, $totalids);
}
return $output;
```

Comment: still no use boss, i'm not getting output.